# Virtualhost: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: php, apache, debian, apache2, virtualhost

I have a problem whenever I try to set-up a virtual host using apache on Debian 10.

I am trying to set-up virtual host on the address **products.crud**. So the directory structure is **var/www/products.crub/web**.

So, I created the Apache Virtual Hosts configuration file in in /etc/apache2/sites-available directory and can I also enabled it in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory. The content of the file named **products.crud.conf** is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName products.crud
DocumentRoot /var/www/products.crud/web
<Directory /var/www/products.crud/web>
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

So, I enabled the domain using:

> $ sudo a2ensite products.crud

And then I tested the syntax using

> $ sudo apachectl configtest

The problem is that I receive this error:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::2ff5:a177:ff45:30b3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
> Syntax OK

#### What I tried to solve the issue

I tried adding the domain in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
#127.0.1.1  terminale
#127.0.0.1  products.test
127.0.0.5   products.crud
```

I also tried to add in apache2.conf:

```
# Global configuration                                                          
#                                                                               
ServerName products.crud
#                                                                               
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's            
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.                                 
#
```

Whenever I try to connect to products.crud I see the localhost main page of apache and not my index.php. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change the ServerName `products.test` to ServerName `products.crud` in your `products.crud.conf` file, like this:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName products.crud
    DocumentRoot /var/www/products.crud/web
    <Directory /var/www/products.crud/web>
        RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that! Anyway, I still get the exact same error:

`AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::2ff5:a177:ff45:30b3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK`

EDIT: formatting

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Yes, I restarted it! In apache2.conf I uncommented `ServerName products.crud` and now I get no errors. The problem is that now products.crud redirects me to the localhost homepage... @Siebe Jongebloed

Comment: So it sort of solved one problem. Now you have another problem. Doe you use .htaccess file which could be responsable for the redirect?
And maybe delete this line in your host-file: 127.0.0.5   products.crud.

Comment: Actually I kind of solved the problem by adding in products.crud.conf `<VirtualHost products.crud:80>`. Now the main problem is that php is not parsed and that the code is read like html

Comment: In stead of solving a sequence of cascading problems, I think it's good to keep this question and answer clean. If you found this answer helped you, please accept. 
And then try to google or ask e new question here about how to enable php using Apache.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to:
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
and insert:
ServerName localhost
and then restart apache by typing into the terminal:
sudo systemctl reload apache2

reference
https://codeinfopark.com/questions/ah00558-apache2-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-using-172-18-0-3-set-the-servername-directive-globally-to-suppress-this-message/